# Can Java 8 Streams operate on an item in a collection, and then remove it?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, filtering, java-stream

Like just about everyone, I'm still learning the intricacies (and loving them) of the new Java 8 Streams API. I have a question concerning usage of streams. I'll provide a simplified example.

Java Streams allows us to take a `Collection`, and use the `stream()` method on it to receive a stream of all of its elements. Within it, there are a number of useful methods, such as `filter()`, `map()`, and `forEach()`, which allow us to use lambda operations on the contents.

I have code that looks something like this (simplified):

```
set.stream().filter(item -> item.qualify())
    .map(item -> (Qualifier)item).forEach(item -> item.operate());
set.removeIf(item -> item.qualify());
```

The idea is to get a mapping of all items in the set, which match a certain qualifier, and then operate through them. After the operation, they serve no further purpose, and should be removed from the original set. The code works well, but I can't shake the feeling that there's an operation in `Stream` that could do this for me, in a single line.

If it's in the Javadocs, I may be overlooking it.

Does anyone more familiar with the API see something like that?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
set.removeIf(item -> {
    if (!item.qualify())
        return false;
    item.operate();
    return true;
});
```

If `item.operate()` always returns `true` you can do it very succinctly.

```
set.removeIf(item -> item.qualify() && item.operate());
```

However, I don't like these approaches as it is not immediately clear what is going on. Personally, I would continue to use a `for` loop and an `Iterator` for this.

```
for (Iterator<Item> i = set.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    Item item = i.next();
    if (item.qualify()) {
        item.operate();
        i.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for using a for loop; don't use streams just so you can fit your code on one line.  Loops are often more readable than streaming solutions, even if they're more verbose.

Comment: I'm a little hesitant to insert state-altering code into `removeIf()`, though I believe this would theoretically work. Additionally, my situation lends itself to functional programming, so my need for streams goes beyond packing everything into a single line; but thank you.

Comment: Using `removeIf` with lambda expression is perfectly legit and it's supposed to be used that way. State altering is part of collection API not stream.

Comment: good example with the for loop, however why do you think it is more clear? for me I actually think that, in this case, the stream solution is more clear

Comment: I really like that iterator snippet.

Answer (score 4):

In one line no, but maybe you could make use of the `partitioningBy` collector:

```
Map<Boolean, Set<Item>> map = 
    set.stream()
       .collect(partitioningBy(Item::qualify, toSet()));

map.get(true).forEach(i -> ((Qualifier)i).operate());
set = map.get(false);
```

It might be more efficient as it avoids iterating the set two times, one for filtering the stream and then one for removing corresponding elements.

Otherwise I think your approach is relatively fine.

Comment: Where's the `remove` in the answer? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

There are many approaches. If you use myList.remove(element) you must override equals(). What I prefer is:

```
allList.removeIf(item -> item.getId().equals(elementToDelete.getId()));
```

Good luck and happy coding :)

Comment: note that this will remove only the first occurrence that matches the predicate

Answer (score 3):

> After the operation, they serve no further purpose, and should be removed from the original set. The code works well, but I can't shake the feeling that there's an operation in Stream that could do this for me, in a single line.

You cannot remove elements from the source of the stream with the stream.  From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

> Most stream operations accept parameters that describe user-specified behavior..... To preserve correct behavior, these behavioral parameters:
>
> - **must be non-interfering (they do not modify the stream source)**; and
> - in most cases must be stateless (their result should not depend on any state that might change during execution of the stream pipeline).

Answer (score 2):

What you really want to do is to partition your set. Unfortunately in Java 8 partitioning is only possible via the terminal "collect" method. You end up with something like this:

```
// test data set
Set<Integer> set = ImmutableSet.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
// predicate separating even and odd numbers
Predicate<Integer> evenNumber = n -> n % 2 == 0;

// initial set partitioned by the predicate
Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> partitioned = set.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(evenNumber));

// print even numbers
partitioned.get(true).forEach(System.out::println);
// do something else with the rest of the set (odd numbers)
doSomethingElse(partitioned.get(false))
```

Updated:

Scala version of the code above

```
val set = Set(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val partitioned = set.partition(_ % 2 == 0)
partitioned._1.foreach(println)
doSomethingElse(partitioned._2)`
```

Comment: Ah, hopefully they'll implement a "`forEachAndRemove`" method one of these days. I don't think that my code would be any clearer, or any faster, if I did that. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Surprisingly you do not need specific methods like that. The same code in Scala makes a lot more sense (see above).

Comment: Where's the `remove` in the answer? What am I missing here?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka elements in the List partitioned.get(false) are the `remove`d ones, and the list in partitioned.get(true) is what remains of the original List after `remov`al. If I got it right.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, your implementation is probably the simplest one.  You might do something deeply evil by modifying state in the `removeIf` predicate, but please don't.  On the other hand, it might be reasonable to actually switch to an iterator-based imperative implementation, which might actually be more appropriate and efficient for this use case.

Comment: I've been thinking about that, but for my actual (unsimplified) implementation, the streams could get to be enormous. I'm running this generally on four to eight core machines; so in spite of the youth of Java's Stream API I am not yet convinced that iterators will be a benefit. `parallel()` could be a saviour here.

Thank you for the prompt response, though!

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your question correctly:

```
set = set.stream().filter(item -> {
    if (item.qualify()) {
        ((Qualifier) item).operate();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 0):

I see Paul's clarity concern when using streams, stated in the top answer. Perhaps adding explaining variable clarifies intentions a little bit.

```
set.removeIf(item -> {
  boolean removeItem=item.qualify();
  if (removeItem){
    item.operate();
  }
  return removeItem;
});
```